# Is there something wrong with the way i'm starting my script? trying to get array to output a different response per answer

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Ok so I think the problem with my code is related to the actual html page i'm activating the code with, but i can't be sure. 
what i'm trying to do is have two questions asked via an array. I want the second question to show "gerp" instead of correct and for it to notify you is you are wrong on question two if you are wrong.

this is what i use on the page to start the "riddles" :

```
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
```

and this is the code i use in the js file that is separate to the html file (sorry if i sound silly, i'm just trying to be specific):

```
 var i = 0;

var myArray = [{
q: "What was her favorite Color?",
a: "purple" }, {
q: "gymhoaccetpptfe",
a: "rev six nine eleven"}];

   function myFunction() {
   var x;
   var name = prompt(myArray[i].q);
  if (name == myArray[i].a) {
    x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + " " + "Correct!" + " " + "Listen!" 
    + " " +
    "http://www.npr.org/2010/02/12/123534818/carl-sagan-and-ann-druyans-ultimate-mix-tape" 
    ;
    i= i + 1 ;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
} else if ((name == myArray[i + 1].a)) {
    x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + " " + "gerp!";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
} else {
    x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + name + " " + "is" + " " + "wrong!";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
}
```

I just want "Gerp" to show up when the second question is answered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

it's because in the first if, you do `i=i+1`, but in the second if, for the gerp, you're checking for i + 1, which would be 2, the third element. unless you need it to be dynamic, just use the corresponding index:

```
...  else if(name == myArray[1].a) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *really* consider fixing your formatting and cleaning up your code. It'll look much nicer and errors will be easier to spot:

```
var questions = [{
    question: 'What was her favorite Color?',
    answer: 'purple',
    message: 'Correct! Listen: http://www.npr.org/2010/02/12/123534818/carl-sagan-and-ann-druyans-ultimate-mix-tape'
}, {
    question: 'gymhoaccetpptfe',
    answer: 'rev six nine eleven',
    message: 'gerp!'
}];

function add_message(text) {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo');

    element.innerHTML = text;

    demo.appendChild(element);
}

function ask_questions(questions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; ) {
        var question = questions[i];
        var response = prompt(question.question);

        if (response == question.answer) {
            add_message(question.message);
            i++;
        } else {
            add_message('"' + response + '" is wrong!');
        }
    }
}

function start_riddles() {
    ask_questions(questions);
}
```